# Loop recurring formula

Tags: google-sheets, formula, timesheet.js

I want to add a recurring formula to my script for a timesheet wherein when I punch out it will calculate the duration of Time In and Time out, then it would lock the values of time in and out and the total duration. Thank you in advance if you would help me out.

```
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}

function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}

function getNextRow() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 1;
}

function getNextRow2() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + 2;
}

function setUser1(x) {
  setValue('I1', 'User 1');
}

function setUser2() {
  setValue('I1', 'User 2');
} 

function addRecord(a, b, c) {
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('A' + row, a);
  setValue('B' + row, b);
  setValue('C' + row, c);
}

function isUserIn(user) {
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  for (var i = lastRow; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (getValue("A" + i) == user) {
      if (getValue("C" + i) > getValue("B" + i)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
}

function punchIN() {
  var user = getValue("I1");
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  addRecord(getValue('I1'), new Date());
}

function punchOut() {
  var user = getValue("I1");
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  if (isUserIn(user)) {
    for (var i = lastRow; i >= 1; i--) {
      if (getValue("A" + i) == user) {
        if (getValue("C" + i) == "") {
          setValue("C" + i, new Date(), "IN");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it should basically look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcKR0.png)

Please help me do this thanks. I actually have no background in coding it would be a big help if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your punchout() function as follow:

```
function punchOut() {
var user = getValue("I1");
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  if (isUserIn(user)) {
    for (var i = lastRow; i >= 1; i--) {
      if (getValue("A" + i) == user) {
        if (getValue("C" + i) == "") {
          setValue("C" + i, new Date());
          var duration = (getValue("C" + i) - getValue("B" + i)) / (60 * 60 * 1000);
          setValue("D" + i, duration);
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B" + i + ":C" + i).setLocked(true);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also you can modify your getNextRow is follow:

```
function getNextNRow(n) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() + n;
}
```

Comment: hey there thanks for the help it works great, its just that .setLocked( ) is not woking this is done in sheets